# Does the package com.google.vr.sdk.controller actually exist?

Tags: android-studio, google-vr, daydream, google-vr-sdk

The Daydream docs have a page for the controller package,  com.google.vr.sdk.controller:
https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/controller/ControllerManager

But at SDK level 25 I can't find that package. Was it removed? Or is it only available at a later version?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your gradle files

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.80.0'
    compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-controller:1.80.0'
}
```

More informations [here](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/get-started)

Comment: Ah yeah, doh. Forgot that. But after I add that I don't get any of the classes. I don't see ControllerManager or anything in that package. In fact AndroidStudio doesn't seem to think there are any public symbols at all.

Comment: @griffin2000 I've updated my answer with the base dependency. You should be able to see the package now (I do).

Comment: I can see the package, but not the classes in it: So this works:
import com.google.vr.sdk.controller.*

But I don't see any classes in tha package, so this doesn't work:
import com.google.vr.sdk.controller.Controller

Or this
import com.google.vr.sdk.controller.ControllerManager

As far as Android Studio is concerned there is nothing public in that package.

Comment: does adding `new ControllerManager(null, null).getController();` to your code work ?

Comment: No, the ControllerManager does not seem to exist in that package (or any of the controller related classes).

Comment: what is your min sdk version ? it should be 19

Comment: We are at 25. Were those classes removed?